# Why is LazyColumn not scrollable using mouse but recycler view is?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is a question of **Why** rather than **How**.

I am using [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to mirror and control my physical test mobile device using my desktop.

I am migrating an app from views to jetpack compose.
This is something I observed and I am curious why this happens so.

Using the desktop mouse scroll wheel, I am able to scroll a `RecyclerView`.

But I am not able to do so in a `LazyColumn`.

**Note:** I am able to scroll the `LazyColumn` using the mouse by click and drag.
Only the scroll wheel is not working.

Code (which I feel is really not relevant)

```
bookingsState?.let { bookings ->
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        items(bookings) { booking: BookingEntity ->
            BookingView(booking)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that this is lack of support on `scrcpy` side, probably to pass events to Compose you have to use some different API from what they're using with `RecyclerView `. You should open an issue there

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, `scrcpy` is expected to pass a system-wide event on scrolling right? How does that differ for views and compose? Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, Spot on. Checked with a similar screen control app and it works as expected. The issue is with `scrcpy` as you mentioned. Though still I am confused on why.

Comment: I'm just guessing, I don't know how exactly does `scrcpy` works. But there may not exist some stable api they can use, so they have to reverse-engineer it. Also Compose is build totally from the ground, and `scrcpy` may use some specific `android.view.View` api, which is not used by Compose.

Comment: Yup, makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*(`scrcpy` author here)*

`scrcpy` just injects *scroll events*, which are handled by the system:
https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/c96f5c70e9c6fe82da059c7d24e77d9730aa7f86/server/src/main/java/com/genymobile/scrcpy/Controller.java#L225-L246

However, the problem might still be explained by incorrect parameters in the scroll event, which happen to work in many case but not all. Such problems already occurred in the past: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/2169

In particular, scroll events are injected with a *touchscreen* as input device, which is probably incorrect. Could you please try with this fix: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/commit/13b8fc0ad9376409a1c93194c6f7c491e51c533d

Here is a binary to replace in your v1.18 release so you can test easily:
[`scrcpy-server`](https://tmp.rom1v.com/scrcpy/scroll_mouse/1/scrcpy-server)
(SHA256: a1db961faf8f567737373f1fa9f39609fede8955b5b28c3f31a06256f54d33d1)

Thank you for your feedback.

---

The problem is the same with a mouse (connected via bluetooth), without scrcpy being involved at all: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/2602#issuecomment-907686669

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. I am not used to mac. (got mac recently) Can you please guide me on where should the `scrcpy-server` file go?

Comment: `/usr/share/scrcpy/scrcpy-server` I guess (replace the existing one). Or better, just download it anywhere, then execute `SCRCPY_SERVER=/path/to/your/scrcpy-server scrcpy` (so it just use this server for this specific execution only).

Comment: In `usr/share`, I couldn't find a `scrcpy` directory. I tried with the second method, still, it is not scrolling using the mouse scroll wheel.

Comment: OK, then it was not the cause of your issue. If you plug a mouse (with an OTG cable) directly on the device, does scrolling work?

Comment: I have not tried with OTG as I don't have one. In case you missed it, on the same desktop using `scrcpy` I am able to scroll the app when it had recycler view. The issue is when using compose `LazyColumn`. But I tried an alternative of `scrcpy` and that scrolls both recycler view and compose `LazyColumn`.

Comment: Could you please publish a minimal sample app (source code) on github or somewhere (ready to build with gradle) so that I can check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236518/discussion-between-abhimanyu-and-rom1v).